# Xcode C++ Struct Order

Tags: c++, struct

The code is given below is not allowed to compile because of struct's order. **song_node** struct has ***playlist*** variable and **playlist** struct has ***song_node*** variable.

This code is runned on Visual Studio or gcc compile.

```
struct song_node {
    song* data;
    song_node* next;
    song_node* prev;
    playlist* parent;
};

struct playlist {
    int songnumber;
    char* name = new char[LNAME_LENGTH];
    song_node* head;
    playlist* next;
    playlist* prev;
};
```

I am new on Xcode. What is the problem in this code?

Comment: It's enough to add a `struct playlist;` forward declaration before `song_node`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a *forward declaration* for the class `playlist`:

```
struct playlist; //Here

struct song_node {
    song* data;
    song_node* next;
    song_node* prev;
    playlist* parent;
};

struct playlist {
    int songnumber;
    char* name = new char[LNAME_LENGTH];
    song_node* head;
    playlist* next;
    playlist* prev;
};
```

Then the compiler knows about `playlist`and you can use it in `song_node` even though it's not implemented (yet).

Comment: Is there another way? It works so thank you but I just wonder why it is working on other platforms but here give the error?

Comment: what other platforms are you talking about?

Comment: Visual Studio or gcc compile.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a forward declaration.

```
struct playlist;

struct song_node {
    song* data;
    song_node* next;
    song_node* prev;
    playlist* parent;
};

struct playlist {
    int songnumber;
    char* name = new char[LNAME_LENGTH];
    song_node* head;
    playlist* next;
    playlist* prev;
};
```

The compiler needs to know that there is something like a `playlist` when you want to use it within `song_node`. By forward-declaring playlist you tell the compiler that such an object exists.